# Better Platform to store data out of ethereum blockchain

Tags: transactions, database, decentralization

What can be the better alternative for someone who is willing to store data off-chain?

What smart-contract suppose to do is just sign a transaction and perform, while every piece of information needs to be saved off-chain. IPFS is one of the popular distributed storage systems but is there any other platform that Dapps usually pick for storage?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't rights answer to your question, depends on the use case and on the business model.

If you want to adopt a full decentralize ecosystem use a distributed decentralize storage (like ipfs, storj ecc)

If you want to store data offchain use legacy file system :)
Database or local system. There isnt a better way but a different model to use data.

Database for caching  bypass performance
Local storage for security ex app mobile
Nosql db for not structured data
Elastic stack for analytic
And so

Comment: Yeah, the requirement is such that smart-contract data storage may change over time so everything I would like to store in off-chain. SO that overtime if the contract gets changed then I can easily retrieve the information saved so far.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the first answer, there is a distributed storage platform, called Swarm (https://swarm.ethereum.org/), that has been specially built to work with Ethereum dApps.